# Making telephone calls

Tags: swift, ios10

I've built a simple iOS App using Swift and trying to create a button that allows a user to dial a preconfigured number.

Below is the code I currently have in place, which appears correct from the documentation I've been following but Xcode is displaying the error:

> Variable used within its own initial value'

The line that is displaying the error is when I'm trying to call the UIApplication.

```
@IBAction func contact_number_button(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let contact_number = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    let phoneURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(contact_number)") {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(phoneURL)
}
```

Comment: are you testing in device?

Comment: Hi, I have not tried testing it in a simulator, as I've read calls don't work within simulators. Right now, this is just XCode presenting me with an error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string:"tel://\(contact_number)") {
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
 if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
     application.openURL(phoneCallURL);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `phoneURL` is available in this way:

```
if let phoneURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(contact_number)") {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(phoneURL)
}
```

Try to take a look at [Optional Chaining as an Alternative to Forced Unwrapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Answer (score 0):

Second edition with a good practise instead:

```
@IBAction func contact_number_button(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let contact_number = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    if  let phoneURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(contact_number)") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(phoneURL)
    }
}
```

Edition with the unwrapping the optional:

I believe the issue you are having is with an opened brace, try this:

```
@IBAction func contact_number_button(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let contact_number = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    let phoneURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(contact_number)") 
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(phoneURL!)
}
```

Comment: Nop youre code will not execute because of the phoneURL is optional

Comment: Edited with the unwrapped optional

Comment: it is bad practice to force unwrapping like that

Comment: True that, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all of your help!

All of the answers here have led me to the solution. I think I've literally picked the wrong week to start teaching myself to code in Swift and to code all together! XCode 8.0 keeps telling me certain commands in iOS10 have been depreciated, one of which was the openURL command. Below is the code that is now allowing me to make working calls to the preconfigured number using my iPhone 6S (iOS 10). XCode is still telling me the command openURL has been depreciated, but it's working. If the below is incorrect or there is a better way, please feel free to correct! Thank you all so much! This is my first ever post and your support has been amazing!

```
                                                               @IBAction func contact_number_button(_ sender: AnyObject) {        
    let contact_number = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    if let phoneURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(contact_number)"){
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(phoneURL as URL)

    }
}
```